# Wolfram Mathematica. How to hide one in power

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a code

```
(# /. {x_, y_} -> Defer[x^y]) & /@ FactorInteger[x]
```

that gives me for example

```html
 {63, {3<sup>2</sup>, 7<sup>1</sup>}}
```

How can I replace 7^1 to simple 7

Comment: add a replacement rule to handle the special case first `{x_,1}->x`

Comment: When I use
(# /. {{x_, 1} -> x, {x_, y_} -> Defer[x^y]}) & /@ FactorInteger[x]
I have
{63, {3^2, 63}}
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `(# /. {{x_, 1} -> x, {x_, y_} -> Defer[x^y]}) & /@ FactorInteger[63]` gives me `{3^2,7}`  try restarting your kernel if its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a number:

```
number = 2^3 3^7 5^2 7^1
```

> 3061800

then I think this is a bit better

```
Replace[FactorInteger[number], {{x_, 1} -> x, {x_, y_} -> Defer[x^y]}, {1}]
```

[image]

You do not really need to `Map` aka `/@` if you use `ReplaceAll` aka `/.`

In future go to:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, right formula is  FactorInteger[
  x] /. {{u_, 1} -> u, {u_Integer, v_Integer} -> Defer[u^v]}